# componentes vue no funcionan si no pongo .default ¿Para que sirve el .default? antes no era necesario

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Estoy haciendo un nuevo proyecto en laravel, entonces  empece a hacer componentes vue como los había estado haciendo en otro proyecto

bien, ahora resulta que eel app.js

debo de poner esto

```
Vue.component('v-posts', require('./components/posts.vue').default);
```

No entiendo porque debo de poner default, Ya que si no lo pongo me muestra error

No puede ser que sea una actualización ya que en mi anterior proyecto lo empece en octubre.

Y según estas respuestas son de 2017

[Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1882)

¿Ahora no entiendo que pasa?

no puedo hacer mis componentes normalmalmente

```
Vue.component('v-posts', require('./components/posts.vue'));
```

sin poner default.

```html
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.7",
        "vue-infinite-loading": "^2.4.3",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.22"
    }
}
```

Se me hace todo raro, porque encontré información de hace algunos meses, lo cual en octb del 2018 no necesitaba .default y por lo que veo debo de usar .default en todos mis componentes. **¿Para que sirve  el .default?**

Comment: Nunca había visto esa sintaxis con require, ni siquiera aparece en la documentación de Vue, ¿con qué fin usas esta sintaxis con require en vez de las que aparecen en la documentación?

Comment: Tu `example-component` está declarado con `.default`? También **podría ser** un error por el nombre del componente. Ej: `ExampleComponent`por convención, debes colocar el nombre de tu componente en mayúsculas y seguido de "Component". Laravel es un **"opinionated framework"** por lo que te puede generar complicaciones por errores tan sutiles como esos. Saludos!

Comment: @Shaz así es como lo  había estado haciendo con larave+vue de ese modo

Comment: @FranIslas Es que había estado trabajando en otro proyecto y los hacía así, v-post , v-comentarios, v-etc...- hasta ahorita que me pide el .default

Comment: No respondió mi pregunta, yo he hecho muchos proyectos con Laravel y Vue y nunca he visto esa forma de registrar componentes.

Comment: @Shaz no lo sé entonces :( porque así he estado viendo algunos videos . ¿Cómo los hace usted?

Comment: mmmm se te estará escapando algo en tus componentes? yo actualmente los estoy registrando así: `Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));` y no tengo ningún problema.

Comment: @FranIslas de hecho así es como los tengo. pero he creado dos proyectos minis. en donde uso vue.  y ahora me pide que use .default. es como si mi versión se hubiera atrasado? pero no se que paso Jajaj :(

Comment: Acá explican que es lo que pasa y como solucionarlo https://laravel-mix.com/docs/4.0/upgrade